# TweenLite Design Pattern

Tags: flash, actionscript, gsap

Just curious. TweenLite/TweenMax is a very common animation library, and I was wondering how someone would classify the design pattern used in TweenLite.
For those of you unfamiliar, here's some example code from their website:

```
//import the GreenSock classes
import com.greensock.*;
import com.greensock.easing.*;

//tween the MovieClip named "mc" to an alpha of 0.5 over the course of 3 seconds
TweenLite.to(mc, 3, {alpha:0.5});

//scale myButton to 150% (scaleX/scaleY of 1.5) using the Elastic.easeOut ease for 2     seconds
TweenLite.to(myButton, 2, {scaleX:1.5, scaleY:1.5, ease:Elastic.easeOut});

//tween mc3 in FROM 100 pixels above wherever it is now, and an alpha of 0. (notice the vars object defines the starting values instead of the ending values)
TweenLite.from(mc3, 1, {y:"-100", alpha:0});

//after a delay of 3 seconds, tween mc for 5 seconds, sliding it across the screen by changing its "x" property to 300, using the Back.easeOut ease to make it shoot past it and   come back, and then call the onFinishTween() function, passing two parameters: 5 and mc
TweenLite.to(mc, 5, {delay:3, x:300, ease:Back.easeOut, onComplete:onFinishTween,  onCompleteParams:[5, mc]});
function onFinishTween(param1:Number, param2:MovieClip):void {
trace("The tween has finished! param1 = " + param1 + ", and param2 = " + param2);
}

//call myFunction() after 2 seconds, passing 1 parameter: "myParam"
TweenLite.delayedCall(2, myFunction, ["myParam"]);

//use the object-oriented syntax to create a TweenLite instance and store it so we can   reverse, restart, or pause it later.
var myTween:TweenLite = new TweenLite(mc2, 3, {y:200, alpha:0.5, onComplete:myFunction});

//some time later (maybe in by a ROLL_OUT event handler for a button), reverse the tween, causing it to go backwards to its beginning from wherever it is now.
myTween.reverse();

//pause the tween
myTween.pause();

//restart the tween
myTween.restart();

//make the tween jump to exactly its 2-second point
myTween.currentTime = 2;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Where they are passing around associative arrays rather then calling actual functions, it is the magic container anti-pattern: http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?MagicContainer. It's considered a bad idea because you should really be calling specific functions not constructing crazy bags of parameters.

Comment: And still, TweenLite is popular and widely used. Goes to show that following design patterns is not always required to make successful software, I guess.

Comment: @LarsBlåsjö, yes... although part of using that pattern is an attempt to get around the limitations of the language so I don't blame them too much.

Comment: @LarsBlåsjö , tweenlite is designed this way because objects in flash are dynamic, and it isn't directly targeted toward displayobjects, you can use tweenlite on anything object and interpolate any property of that objects through a number of frames or time. really the only negatives i can see with the pattern are maybe higher chances of reserved keyword conflicts and some sacrifice of efficiency (although tweenlite runs way faster than most tweening engines). i asked the question because i really love how it was designed!

Comment: Even worse, TweenLite uses static methods and functions, and forces you to mix instances and statics, since neither provides all the functionality.